# The W3C Feed Validation Service finds my dates problematic even though i generated them with DATE_RFC822

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, rss

I've been validating my RSS feed at http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi
it gives me the warning:

In addition, interoperability with the widest range of feed readers could be improved by implementing the following recommendation.

```
line 10, column 46: Problematical RFC 822 date-time value: Mon, 15 Dec 14 15:26:54 +0000 

            <pubDate>Mon, 15 Dec 14 15:26:54 +0000</pubDate>
```

I generate the date with php and wordpress

```
      date(DATE_RFC822, strtotime(get_post_time('Y-m-d H:i:s',$postid));
```

The date is definite formatted as DFC822, as i'm using PHPs built in RFC822 definition
what is the validator complaining about, and how to i fix it.

Comment: why bother with strtotime and date? get_post_time is already using date() internally, so why not just `get_post_time('r', $postid)`? You're just forcing php to do a hell of a lot of useless work with timestamp->string->timestamp->string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a much simpler `get_the_time('r', $postid)`.

- `get_the_time` will get the post's published time
- the `r` argument will automatically format the date as RFC 2822

As far as I can see, there's no reason to get the post time, parse to timestamp and then format it again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the W3C Validator wants dates with four digit years not two digit years, so the right date is:

```
 date("D, d M Y H:i:s O",get_post_time($postid))
```